# Multiple columns in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Problem:  how to simplify the code below, as I'm aiming towards 30 different properties in the thing class.

The code looks for uniqueness in a 'thing' property.

```
public class thing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
}

public List<thing> SeeIfAnyInListHaveAUniqueSingleColumn(List<thing> listOfThings)
    {
        // try colour
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, thing>> thingQuery2 = from t in listOfThings
                                                            group t by t.Colour;
        List<thing> listOfThingsFound = new List<thing>();
        foreach (var thingGroup in thingQuery2)
        {
            if (thingGroup.Count() == 1)
            {
                foreach (thing thing in thingGroup) // there is only going to be 1
                    listOfThingsFound.Add(thing);
            }
        }

        // try position
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, thing>> thingQuery3 = from t in listOfThings
                                                            group t by t.Position;

        foreach (var thingGroup in thingQuery3)
        {
            if (thingGroup.Count() == 1)
            {
                foreach (thing thing in thingGroup) // there is only going to be 1
                    listOfThingsFound.Add(thing);
            }
        }
        return listOfThingsFound;
    }
```

Downloadable code on http://www.programgood.net/2010/11/06/FindingUniquenessInData.aspx

Comment: Do you want to know if any property is distinct? Or are you going to always know in code which property you are checking for?

Comment: Henk - good question!  Yes, all properties are currently strings.

Comment: Jayrdub - currently I'm checking for any singular distinct property, so any colour that is unique, any position that is unique etc..  Yes, in code I will always know what I'm checking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you abstract away the `FindUnique` operation, you can more easily write the tests:

```
static IEnumerable<T> FindDistinct<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                            Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
{
    return from item in source
           group item by keySelector(item) into grp
           where grp.Count() == 1
           from single in grp
           select single;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
var thingsWithUniqueName = listOfThings.FindDistinct(t => t.Name);
var thingsWithUniquePosition = listOfThings.FindDistinct(t => t.Position);
var thingsWithUniqueHeight = listOfThings.FindDistinct(t => t.Height);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would like to write code like:

```
foreach var property in Thing.Properties
{
   IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, thing>> thingQuery2 = from t in listOfThings    
                                                        group t by t.property;    
    List<thing> listOfThingsFound = new List<thing>();    
    foreach (var thingGroup in thingQuery2)    
    {    
        if (thingGroup.Count() == 1)    
        {    
            foreach (thing thing in thingGroup) // there is only going to be 1    
                listOfThingsFound.Add(thing);    
        }    
    }
     ...
 }
```

You can only do that through Reflection and that is something you should stay away from. The only thing I can think of is store the properties in some kind of collection, like a dictionary and iterate *that*.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that Gabe has provided the same answer I was about to post. I thought I would post this anyway just to reinforce that this answer is a good strong use of LINQ. **Please accept Gabe's answer rather than this one.** Well done Gabe!

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereUniqueByKey<T, P>(
    this IEnumerable<T> @this, Func<T, P> keySelector)
{
    return @this
        .GroupBy(keySelector)
        .Where(gt => gt.Count() == 1)
        .SelectMany(gt => gt, (_, t) => t);
}
```

As per Gabe's answer, my function is an extension method, and it needs to be defined in a static class. The only real difference between our answers is that Gabe has used the LINQ query syntax and I used direct LINQ method calls. The result is the same and so is the usage:

```
var thingsWithUniqueName = listOfThings.WhereUniqueByKey(t => t.Name);
var thingsWithUniquePosition = listOfThings.WhereUniqueByKey(t => t.Position);
var thingsWithUniqueHeight = listOfThings.WhereUniqueByKey(t => t.Height);
```

Comment: Ha! I was originally going to post the fluent version and decided at the last minute to use query comprehension syntax.